# No Font-Awesome icons on buttons will vertical-align

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

So I have this app with some buttons, that have some Font Awesome icons on them. These buttons are placed inside a Bootcards header.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right ">  
    <i class="fa fa-pencil" ></i>
</button>
```

Now the problem is that it looks like this:

[image: Misplaced icon 1]

Then I have this other one with text, which doesn't look right either:

[image: Misplaced icon 2]

This one has the following HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="publishMessage()">
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    Publiser
</button>
```

Now, after some googling around, I found that `vertical-align` should help me out, but it simply does nothing. All approaches I've found simply creates paddings or margins around the icon, so that it still touches the bottom of the button, but on a much bigger button.

Since I'm not that familiar with this language, I wonder why just adding some CSS like `.fa {vertical-align: middle;}` (or with my own class name) does not work, and what I need to do.

**UPDATE:** Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uz3tu23s/5/).

Comment: You shouldn't need to - does the text button look correct without the icon Can this be viewed online?

Comment: Can you create fiddle or any demo?

Comment: You have any code that is overriding this. It seems like is a padding-bottom removed or something like this. With a pure bootstrapping button your icon will be perfect. You can workaround in: http://www.bootply.com to check that I saying. We need to view more of your code to help you

Comment: You probably should define a `line-height`. Can you provide a demo please ?

Comment: Yes, adding a demo, thanks!

Comment: I think that some container of your buttons is overwriting the padding properties of the button because this is how it looks actually : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayadi102/0pknawag/) , can you provide a fiddle link as well with all your code on so we can debug it

Comment: Removed my custom CSS from the fiddle, and I the problem persists. Maybe it has something to do with the Bootcards-library that contains the buttons in both cases, but there should be some way of overriding it?

Comment: Inspect the element and it is easy to see it it the ios and android stylesheets that are doing it.

Comment: @epascarello You're right! Removing Android and iOS-Bootcards makes the  icons look right on desktop. This is a problem on the libraries part, then?

Comment: Can you see if my answer works for you? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is simple. You should change

```
<i class="fa fa-check"></i>
```

by

```
<span class="fa fa-check"></span>
```

Then simply make the span height equal to his container.
And make use use of vertical-align property. 
css for the span

```
height: inherit;
vertical-align: inherit;
```

**Update:** http://jsfiddle.net/uz3tu23s/4/

Comment: Thanks, this vertical-aligns the icons, which was what I asked. For reference, removing the iOS- Android-versions of Bootcards also solves this problem.

Comment: Why change from i to span?

Comment: @RemiSture The difference between <span> and <i> is that <i> was orriginaly intended for italics font, while <span> is intended to encapsulate a piece of content without changing any css rules immediately. In other words <span> can be used for any custom css action you want to apply.

Therefor, normally I use span instead of <i> and it was a fast and easy fix for this problem.

Comment: Okay, I was just wondering, since Font Awesome suggests this markup: ´<i class="fa fa-fighter-jet" aria-hidden="true"></i>´

Comment: @RemiSture Font awesome doesn't "suggest" in any place to use <i> 
Have a look here: http://fontawesome.io/examples/  and read the paragraph of the Basic Icons section. It says: "Font Awesome is designed to be used with inline elements (we like the <i> tag for brevity, but using a <span> is more semantically correct)."  :)

Answer (score 0):

I developed this jquery code to use one bootcards stylesheet at a time according to the type of the device, so you won't miss the bootcards styling that you need it, and you won't get the styling of the iOS or the android for the desktop or something.

Also , don't forget to include the bootstrap css file.

```
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().search("android") > -1){
            return 'Android';
        }
    },
    iOS: function() {
        if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().search("iphone") > -1 || navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().search("ipad") > -1 ||navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().search("ipod") > -1){
            return 'iOS';
        }
    },
    desktop: function(){
        if(!(isMobile.Android()) && !(isMobile.iOS())){
            return 'Desktop';
        }
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.desktop());
    }
};

var op = isMobile.any();
console.log(op);

    var ios="<link rel='stylesheet' href='cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootcards/1.0.0/css/bootcards-ios.min.css'>";
    var and="<link rel='stylesheet' href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootcards/1.0.0/css/bootcards-android.min.css'>";
   var desk="<link rel='stylesheet' href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootcards/1.0.0/css/bootcards-desktop.min.css'>";
if(op == "iOS"){
    $(ios).appendTo("head");
}else if(op == "Android"){
    $(and).appendTo("head");
}else{
    $(desk).appendTo("head");
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayadi102/uz3tu23s/9/).

I know that you got your answer, but i think that it's good to share that with you people.

Comment: Looks like it works on desktop at least. I don't really need it on the other two platforms this round, but if we need to develop something for those platforms, I'll keep this in mind. Thanks!